# Free visual studio working on Windows XP?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I want to create simple .NET web page. Where can I download a free version of Visual Studio which would run on Windows XP SP3 on a laptop?

I tried various versions and links from http://www.visualstudio.com, but whatever I download, it states I have the wrong version of Windows.

Comment: Windows XP *is unsupported*. Pages with current products won't display anything about it. You could try to google for older versions until you find one that works. VS 2010 Express definitely works, 2012 probably (never tried it). I don't think you'll find any listings in Microsoft sites though

Comment: You may need the code to *run* on Windows XP, but do you truly lack access to a later machine on which you can do the development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer for a link to vs2010 express.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061811/how-to-get-download-link-to-vs2010-express-for-use-in-a-download-manager

The download link still works. Additionally, here is the readme, which states xp sp3 is supported.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=151235

Edit: Word of warning, using this older version of visual studio would mean you'd be limited to much older .net technology. MVC may not be supported, if that's something you're looking to use, and VS2010 only supports up to .NET 4.0, where as 4.6 is the latest.